# Why do IDEs have Projects?

Tags: ide

Why do IDEs structure code as "Projects" or "Solutions"? And no, I'm not trying to troll, I really want to know what people use them for.

It always seems to me like "Project" is just a redundant alias for "executable", and I find the "Project" structure tends to get in my way when I want to share code across several executable processes. This is especially true in languages like Java, where there's already a rigorous packaging system for organizing code with, but it applies to pretty much every IDE I've seen. So why do they always adopt this structure? Is there some trick to using it?

Comment: It really depends on which IDE you're talking about. Different IDEs use the terms in slightly different ways. But no, Project definitely *doesn't* always mean "executable".

Comment: Many IDEs support projects with multiple targets which will typically be a mixture of libraries and executables sharing a common code base. So "project" is a much broader term than "executable".

Comment: Can you give me an example Paul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It always seems to me like "Project" is just a redundant alias for "executable",

I actually tend to think of "project" more as a "compilation unit" or a "deployment item" - at least for most compiled languages.  Projects typically map to a single executable *or library* (or other compilation unit in languages where that's supported).

As such, a "project" is a very valuable method of organization.

Answer (score 1):

Not all IDEs use these names, but in general, they are a way to organize code.

This is needed in any code base of a certain size - some sort of hierarchy that helps and logically separate code components from each other.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can contain multiple projects. This concept is very much useful when you have a tiered software achitecture.

e.g. A solution can have following projects:

- Data Access Layer Project
- Business Layer Project
- Presentation Layer Project

Every Project (tier) has a specific purpose in the same website.